# How to move files down a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I have inherited a folder structure on a project and would like to simplify it a bit. I have a root full of folders (1st level) and each of those folders has a number of folders in it (2nd level) and each of those folders has a some files inside. It looks something like this:

```
root
|-- dir1
|    |-- dir1.1
|    |      +- file1.txt
|    |-- dir1.2
|    |     +- file2.txt
|    +-- dir1.N
|          +- fileN.txt
|-- dir2
|    |-- dir2.1
|          +- file3.txt
|-- dir3
|    |-- dir3.1
|          +- file4.txt
```

etc.

I'd like to remove all of the x.1 folders, simplify the structure, and move all the files from those folders one level down:

```
root
|-- dir1
|     +- file1.txt
|     +- file2.txt
|     +- fileN.txt
|-- dir2
|     +- file3.txt
|-- dir3
|     +- file4.txt
```

How would I go about accomplishing something like this through bash/zsh?

Comment: There is a [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) where you might get more answers.

Comment: @WindowsEscapist: Yes, but shell scripting questions are welcome here, and they are often answered quickly and/or correctly.

Comment: @user1064903: wouldn't that be "one level up"?

Comment: Well, Hi user. Please don't drop "user signature" everywhere. Your user card could be improved for doing that. It follows you everywhere. And, the "Thanks" won't be required while asking question. Instead, you could use "thanks" after getting the answer :-)

Comment: @Scott I know, I'm just making a pre-emptive suggestion (plus the site needs a little attention IMO).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know whether this will work in zsh, but I expect that it will in bash (although I haven’t fully tested it):

```
for f in */*/*
do
        mv "$f" "$(dirname "$(dirname "$f")")"
done

for f in */*
do
        if [ –d "$f" ]
        then
                rmdir "$f"
        fi
done
```

P.S. In Unix (unlike botany; i.e., the real world), trees have their roots at the top. 
Therefore, this operation would be considered moving files ***up*** the directory structure.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly even though I got a bunch of "line 9: [: –d: unary operator expected" which is the "if [ -d "$f" ]" line.

Comment: @user1064903: Interesting.  Maybe `if [[ –d "$f" ]]` will work, but I would have expected either to be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in */*; do
    mv "$d"/* "$d"/..
    rm -r "$d"
done
```

This doesn't work if the second level contains empty directories or files.